Who is J.L.E., one of the dedicatees of Futrelle's collection The Thinking Machine?
Jacques Futrelle's short stories featuring the fictional detective Augustus S. F. X. Van Dusen appeared in various periodicals beginning 1905. In 1907, seven of these stories were collected in The Thinking Machine. Futrelle's dedication reads:

To those two persons who made The Thinking Machine possible
J.L.E., who opened the way, and L.M.F., who guided, advised and encouraged the hand that labored, these tales are gratefully dedicated.
Futrelle, Jacques. The Thinking Machine: Being a True and Complete Statement of Several Intricate Mysteries which came under the Observation of Professor Augustus S. F. X. Van Dusen, PH.D., LL.D., F.R.S., M.D., etc. 1907. Edited, with an introduction and notes, by Leslie S. Klinger. Naperville, IL: Library of Congress/Poison Pen Press, 2023. p. iii. 

L.M.F. is presumably Futrelle's wife, the writer Lily May Futrelle (née Peel). But who is J.L.E.? How did that person "open the way" to The Thinking Machine?
